# Multinomial regression vs LDA

Tags: linear, multinomial-distribution, discriminant-analysis

In a classification problem, I cannot use a simple logit model if my data label (aka., dependent variable) has more than two categories. That leaves me with multinomial regression and Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) and the likes. Why is it that multinomial logit is not as popular as LDA in machine learning? What is the particular advantage that LDA offers?

Comment: There are many questions on this site comparing them. You might want to search "logistic regression and discriminant analysis".

Comment: how do you know that multinomial regression is not as popular as LDA?